# Facebook share button and images

Tags: javascript, facebook, share

I am struggling to insert a link with a FB Share.
The link is calling a JS. JS opens a popup and my image is missing.

I have 2 options:
1. sharer.php
2. API?

---

1: THIS IS NOT SHOWING MY PHOTO!!!

```
function fbs_click(id, photo) {
    var adv_url = encodeURIComponent("https://www.bikesquare.com.au/product/detail?advertiseId=" + "e77180f8439fe2810143be28c40e000e");
    var photo_url = encodeURIComponent("https://www.bikesquare.com.au/resources/IMG_0554.JPG"); //THIS IS A REAL IMAGE - ONLY FOR TEST!!!

    var new_url="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100";
    new_url += "&p[url]="  + adv_url;
    new_url +="&p[images][0]=" + photo_url;
    new_url +="&p[summary]=TEST";
    new_url +="&p[title]=TITLE";

    window.open(new_url, 'Share on FaceBook', 'left=20,top=20,width=550,height=400,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,resizable=1');
    return false; //FOR TEST ONLY
}
```

2: THIS IS SHOWING MY PHOTO, BUT ONLY I CAN SHARE!! Other FB accounts CANNOT

```
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=[MY SECRET API ID]&link=' +
    encodeURIComponent('https://www.bikesquare.com.au/product/detail? advertiseId=') + id +
    '&picture=' + encodeURIComponent(photo_url) +
    '&name=' + encodeURIComponent('BikeSquare Advertise') +
    '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.bikesquare.com.au/');

window.open(url, 'Share on FaceBook', 'left=20,top=20,width=550,height=400,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,resizable=1');
```

As you can see ladies and gentlemen, I have 2 options. Opt 1 not showing photo. Opt 2 requires a APP ID from FB DEV but only I can share it (photo looks good). Other accounts cannot...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

started to use FB API method and discovered that was on DEV MODE not on public mode...